# SendGrid seemingly ignoring clicktracking: "off" attribute in HAML template (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, haml, sendgrid

I have an e-mail that is constructed in HAML template. Once the e-mail is sent to SendGrid (where clicktracking is enabled globally), the clicktracking="off" attribute is ignored and the corresponding href link is tagged with UTM codes. Using Ruby 3.0.3

The e-mail contains an anchor that looks like this in HAML:

```
%a.btn.btn-primary{clicktracking: "off", style: "color: #FFFFFF;", href: "https://some_link.com/whatever}= s.t('some_text')
```

Ruby maintains the order of hash attributes and most notably in the actual e-mail, this attribute is not present. Any thoughts with respect to diagnosing this?

Comment: Can you share the resulting HTML code, before it is passed to SendGrid?

Comment: The link renders as such in HTML

<a class="btn btn-primary v-align-middle" clicktracking="off" href="https://example.com" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Download</a>